# Access nested JSON data using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data like a below format:

```
var jsonData = {
     "@type": "DimensionSearchService",
         "name": "Dimension Search Service",
         "dimensionSearchResults": {
         "@type": "DimensionSearchResults",
             "totalNumResults": 20,
             "dimensionSearchGroups": [{
             "@class": "com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.DimensionSearchGroup",
                 "displayName": "CHEMICAL GROUP",
                 "dimensionSearchValues": [{
                 "@class": "com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.DimensionSearchValue",
                     "multiSelect": true,
                     "navigationState": "?N=4294957096",
                     "contentPath": "\/guidedsearch",
                     "count": 1,
                     "siteRootPath": "\/services",
                     "ancestors": [],
                     "label": "acidic drugs",
                     "properties": {}
             }, {
                 "@class": "com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.DimensionSearchValue",
                     "multiSelect": true,
                     "navigationState": "?N=4294958340",
                     "contentPath": "\/guidedsearch",
                     "count": 1,
                     "siteRootPath": "\/services",
                     "ancestors": [],
                     "label": "anti diabetic drugs",
                     "properties": {}
             }, {
                 "@class": "com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.DimensionSearchValue",
                     "multiSelect": true,
                     "navigationState": "?N=4294957903",
                     "contentPath": "\/guidedsearch",
                     "count": 1,
                     "siteRootPath": "\/services",
                     "ancestors": [],
                     "label": "anti viral drugs",
                     "properties": {}
             }, {
                 "@class": "com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.DimensionSearchValue",
                     "multiSelect": true,
                     "navigationState": "?N=4294958300",
                     "contentPath": "\/guidedsearch",
                     "count": 1,
                     "siteRootPath": "\/services",
                     "ancestors": [],
                     "label": "antiestrogen drugs",
                     "properties": {}
             }]
             }]
         }
 };
```

Actually I wanted to get the **label** value from this JSON data. However my script is giving me the following error. Any idea what is wrong ?

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for (var z = 0; z < parsed.length; z++) {
    var response = parsed.dimensionSearchResults.dimensionSearchGroups[z].dimensionSearchValues[z].label;
    console.log(response);
}
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dimensionSearchValues' of undefined
```

Comment: `jsonData` is already a Javascript object, you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`. JSON is a string, not an object.

Comment: Someone reformatted your question nicely for you. Why did you undo it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have `var jsonData = { ...` then the data you have *is not JSON*, it's just a normal JavaScript object. You don't need to parse it anymore.

The second problem is that the object is not an array so it doesn't have a `length` attribute. You probably want to loop through `jsonData.dimensionSearchResults.dimensionSearchGroups` instead (which *is* an array), and then through `dimensionSearchValues` (which is also an array).

```
for( var i = 0; i < jsonData.dimensionSearchResults.dimensionSearchGroups.length; i++) {
    for( var j = 0; j < jsonData.dimensionSearchResults.dimensionSearchGroups[i].dimensionSearchValues.length; j++ ) {
        var response = jsonData
            .dimensionSearchResults
            .dimensionSearchGroups[i]
            .dimensionSearchValues[j]
            .label;

        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a coupple of points.

1) You don't need to use JSON.Parse as the JSON Object will already be loaded in the variable.

2) Your JSON is not Valid.[image]

Try validating the JSON using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score -1):

update your code as below and test
http://jsfiddle.net/Kr3gw/1/

```
for( var i = 0; i < jsonData.dimensionSearchResults.dimensionSearchGroups.length; i++) {
for( var j = 0; j < jsonData.dimensionSearchResults.dimensionSearchGroups[i].dimensionSearchValues.length; j++ ) {
```